# why precise accelerometer do not exist

Tags: acceleration, technology

When i read about how the concept works, it looks pretty solid. But in reality accelerometers are just so imprecise that they need to be configured with alternative ways to correct their positions.

I am talking about using accelerometer to measure position. Sounds very solid, but then fails to be practical for other than very limited uses.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're being a bit harsh on the accelerometer designers. There are [some extremely accurate accelerometers out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIGA_accelerometer).

The trouble is that to get your velocity from the accelerometer you need to integrate the acceleration with respect to time:

$$ v = \int a(t) dt $$

Suppose there is a tiny error in your accelerometer reading (call this $\epsilon$) then the integral becomes:

$$ v = \int \left(a(t) + \epsilon\right) dt = \int a(t) dt + \epsilon t $$

So the error in velocity is:

$$ \Delta v = \epsilon t $$

and it increases linearly with time. Even a tiny error will become a significant error in velocity if you wait long enough. But what's worse is that to get position you have to integrate velocity with respect to time:

$$ s = \int v(t) = \int\int \left(a(t)+\epsilon\right) dt $$

And the error in position becomes

$$ \Delta s = \frac{\epsilon}{2}t^2 $$

So the error in your position increases quadratically with time. Even the most precisely made acelerometers will have some error, and because that error produces an error in position that increases quadratically with time you inevitably need to check the position with some external source every now an then. Still, the accuracy is good enough [to guide nuclear missiles](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Usa/Weapons/Airs.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Precise accelerometer do exist - it's just they are expensive, or very expensive, depending on your definition of "precise".

The device you are talking about is called an intertial measurement unit, consisting of three sensors for acceleration, and three for rotation.

I remember there was a study about comparing these devices in the whole price range - the upper bound was something like 20000USD, maybe more. I'll try to find a reference.